# Como fazer um Border-Radius Invertido?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estava testando o `border-radius` e me surgiu uma dívida... Existe alguma forma de com CSS inverter o raio de curvatura do `border-radius`?

Esse é o formato do shape que eu gostaria de obter

[image: exemplo visual de elemento com border-radius invertido]

Mas pela documentação parece que o `border-radius` **não aceita valores negativos**

```css
.container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 160px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: -20px; /* não aceita valor negativo */
}
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, green, blue);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Então ficou a dúvida, como conseguir essa forma nos cantos só com CSS e continuar visualizando a imagem ou a cor de fundo do `background` da página?

> ***OBS:** Não posso usar SVG ou Clip-Path*

Comment: Tem que ser com `<div>`? Isso aí pode ser facilmente resolvido com `svg`.

Comment: @Renan com SVG ou até Clip-Phat fica fácil mesmo, queria com CSS apenas.

Comment: De uma olhada nesse link: https://codepen.io/sergejmueller/pen/fJEml

Comment: @PedroPaulo legal o exemplo, mas se vc colocar lá um background: red; no body vc vai ver o que acontece... não vai servir pra mim

Comment: Tem uma pergunta no SO que deve adjudar:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22422105/4730201

Comment: @RicardoPontual vou verificar! []´s

Comment: Minha dica é usar `SVG`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters acho que já tenho uma solução :), vou postar em breve, não precisa de SVG, apesar de que também serviria, mas queria apenas com CSS

Comment: Ta muito complicado. Os programadores que fizeram o html deveriam ter pensado nisso. Até parece que estamos no tempo da roda quadrada do html.
Eu estava precisando arredondar abrindo (por fora e não por dentro) os cantos arredondados de uma div, pra fazer uma aba semelhante as abas dos navegadores.

Comment: @Alencar Se vc quer o formato normal basta usar border-radius, e a culpa eh do CSS não do html ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seguindo a ideia semelhante a do Wallace, encontrei este link da *Lea Verou*:

- http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/beveled-corners-negative-border-radius-with-css3-gradients/

A diferença é que com isto é possível aplicar a transparência e assim pode mudar a cor de fundo facilmente.

No exemplo tem borda arredonda invertida e também cantos em corte diagonal (chanfro).

> Note que no exemplo tanto dentro de `linear-gradient` quano dentro de `radial-gradient` tem `#fff`, para trocar a cor do elemento troque estes `#fff`, e deve ser feito o mesmo em:
>
> ```
> background: #fff; /* fallback */
> ```

```css
/**
 * Beveled corners & negative border-radius with CSS gradients
 */

.bevel {    
 background: #fff; /* fallback */
 background:
  linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 10px, #fff 0) top left,
  linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 10px, #fff 0) top right,
  linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 10px, #fff 0) bottom right,
  linear-gradient(45deg,  transparent 10px, #fff 0) bottom left;
 background-size: 50% 50%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.bevel.round {
 background-image:
  radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #fff 15px),
  radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #fff  15px),
  radial-gradient(circle at 100% 100%, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #fff 15px),
  radial-gradient(circle at 0 100%, rgba(204,0,0,0) 14px, #fff 15px);
}

/* esta parte a seguir é somente para testes */
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: red;
    background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,.8) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    animation: cores-animadas 5s infinite;
}

.exemplo {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    padding:13px 15px;
    color: #0c0c0c;
    line-height:1.5;
}

@keyframes cores-animadas
{
    0%   { background-color: red; }
    20%  { background-color: green; }
    40%  { background-color: blue; }
    60%  { background-color: violet; }
    80%  { background-color: orange; }
    100% { background-color: red; }
}
```

```html
<div class="exemplo bevel">
   foo bar baz<br>foo bar baz<br>foo bar baz
</div>

<div class="exemplo bevel round">
   foo bar baz<br>foo bar baz<br>foo bar baz
</div>
```

Comment: Ótimo resultado, e a explicação adicional ajudou bastante!

Answer (score 9):

Cara, minha  humilde sugestão seria usar um `radial-gradient`.

No caso, em cada canto de uma `div` filha, você usaria um `radial-gradient` com a mesma cor que você usa no contêiner pai.

Assim:

```css
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.internal-radius{
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at left top, lightblue 20px, transparent 0), 
    radial-gradient(circle at left bottom, lightblue 20px, transparent 0),
    radial-gradient(circle at right top, lightblue 20px, transparent 0),
    radial-gradient(circle at right bottom, lightblue 20px, transparent 0);
    width: 100%;
}

.container{
   background-color: lightblue;
   padding: 15px;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="internal-radius"></div>
</div>
```

É claro que, ao adicionar um texto dentro da `div` que carrega o `radial-gradient`, o texto vai ficar em cima da "bolinha" do topo. A solução que arrumei foi colocar `padding` na `div.internal-radius` com o mesmo valor de `radial-gradient`, ou seja, `20px`.

```css
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.internal-radius{
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at left top, lightblue 20px, transparent 0), 
    radial-gradient(circle at left bottom, lightblue 20px, transparent 0),
    radial-gradient(circle at right top, lightblue 20px, transparent 0),
    radial-gradient(circle at right bottom, lightblue 20px, transparent 0);
    width: 100%;
}

.container{
   background-color: lightblue;
   padding: 15px;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="internal-radius">
      Meu nome é Wallace e eu sou bonito
    </div>
</div>
```

**Observação**: Pra alegria da gurizada: funciona no Internet Explorer 10.

Honestamente, não é uma das melhores soluções, mas CSS ainda é assim.

Answer (score 7):

A solução que cheguei foi similar a do sr. Wallace, porém utilizei 4 divs dentro de um container para ter a transparência nos cantos.

Cara uma das 4 divs tem um radial gradiente com o centro do circulo alinhado no canto indo do transparente para a cor do background.

Para entender melhor segue o exemplo baseado [nesse artigo](http://lea.verou.me/2011/03/beveled-corners-negative-border-radius-with-css3-gradients/).

```css
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, blue);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 3rem auto;
}

.tl, .tr, .br, .bl {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    /* background-color: #fff; */
    float: left;
}
.tl {
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 0 0,transparent 20px, green 20px);
}
.tr {
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 100% 0,transparent 20px, green 20px);
}
.bl {
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 0 100%,transparent 20px, green 20px);
}
.br {
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 100% 100%,transparent 20px, green 20px);
}
.container p {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="tl"></div>
    <div class="tr"></div>
    <div class="bl"></div>
    <div class="br"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Animi, dolores.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -6):

Resolve, Border corner shape the css
box {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    border-corner-shape: scoop;
    border-radius: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

Comment: Isso não funciona em nenhum browser, e nem pode-se afirmar que algum dia isso vai ser aprovado pela W3C, essa resposta no momento só serve para confundir os usuários. Tente testar as coisas localmente antes de postar como resposta, é só uma dica...